# How to remove entire div from MVC View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing MVC application.

I have a View in which I show the data row wise.

I have placed a remove link in that row, when user click on that link, that row should be remove.

But its not working...

I display the data in following format.

```
  $('#ProductList').append("<div  class='span12' style='margin-left:0px' ><div class='span2'>" +
                "<select class='clsProductId '  name='ProductId' id='ddProductList_" + IDD + "' style = 'font-size:12px;width:200px;margin-right:80px;margin-left:20px;' onchange='get(" + IDD + ")'/> </div>" +
                "<div id='ProductCode_" + IDD + "' class='span1'  style=' margin-left:85px;'></div>" +
                "<div id='Weight_" + IDD + "' class='span1' style=' margin-left:55px;'> </div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:0px;'><input type='text' id='Quantity_" + IDD + "' class='clsQuantity'  name='Quantities' style='width:50px; margin-left:0px;' onblur='StockLinkVisible(" + IDD + ");' /></div>" +
                 "<div class='span1' style='margin-left:0px;'><a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold; color :#ee8929; margin-left:20px;' id='lnkRemove_" + IDD + "' class='clsRemove'  onclick='removeElement(" + IDD + ");'>X</a></div>" +
                 "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:60px;'  id='Bandra_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:60px;'  id='Dadar_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:0px; Width:60px;'    id='Bhivandi_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:40px;'  id='Juhu_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:40px;'  id='Kurla_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:10px; Width:60px;'  id='Dombivali_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:15px; Width:40px;'  id='Worli_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:15px; Width:60px;'  id='Sant_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +
                 "<div class='span1'style='margin-left:0px; Width:40px;'  id='Bandra_" + IDD + "'>123</div>" +


                "<hr></div>");
```

for removing the row I have written the below code...

```
   function removeElement(cnt)
    {

        $("#ProductList").on('click', '#lnkRemove_'+cnt, function () {
            $(this).closest("div").remove(); 
        });
    }
```

Please check image below for better idea...
[image]

Comment: You've already bound inline handler `removeElement()` Why you're doing event delegation again in the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the click event, you call a function

```
onclick='removeElement(" + IDD + ");
```

This function binds another click handler to itself, but doesn't actually do anything. Furthermore, the click handler will look for the closest div, which only wraps the delete button, and so doesn't quite do what you want.

```
 $("#ProductList").on('click', '#lnkRemove_'+cnt, function () {
     $(this).closest("div").remove(); 
 });
```

Here's my suggestion: remove the onclick event and the function, and on document ready, register a generic click action as follows:

```
$('#ProductList').on('click', '.clsRemove', function() { 
    $(this).closest('div.span12').remove();
});
```

I chose the class `span12` as the selector simply because it's the only one I saw that the top-level wrapping div (the "row") had. Feel free to add a more descriptive selector and using that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You no need to call `removeElement` for each element. Just configure the below code in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#ProductList").on('click', '.clsRemove', function () {
        $(this).parents("div.span12:first").remove();
 });
});
```

Comment: `.clsRemove` has no parent with the class `span12`.

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom, see the very first child element of #product. `<div  class='span12'`

Comment: I see it, but the jQuery function [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) will only go a single level up, to the wrapping div, or in this case, a div with the class `span1`. Your filtering selector passed to `.parent()` will make sure that an empty result set is returned, since the wrapping div does not have the class `span12`. The function you're looking for is probably [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), which will continue traversing upwards until a match is found or the end of the DOM is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

update to this:

```
function removeElement(cnt)
{
   $('#lnkRemove_'+cnt).closest("div.span12").remove(); 
}
```

---

You don't need to bind `click` event again instead you can do as suggested or better to delegate the event to the closest static parent *(try unobtrusive js)*:

```
$("#ProductList").on('click', '[id^="lnkRemove"]', function () {
    $(this).closest("div.span12").remove(); 
});
```